# TclOO: Access nested objects

Tags: oop, tcl

Lets presume we have two classes as follows:

```
oo::class create InsideThing {
    constructor {} {
        puts "Made a [self] that is an InsideThing"
    }
    destructor {
        puts "Deleted a [self] that is an InsideThing"
    }
    method echo {text} {
        puts "[self]: $text"
    }
}
oo::class create Container {
    constructor {} {
        puts "Created a [self] that is a Container"
        InsideThing create inner1
        InsideThing create inner2
    }
    destructor {
        puts "Deleted a [self] that is a Container"
    }
    method echo1 {text} {
        # how to do something like this:
        $inner1 echo $text
    }
}
```

How would I go about accessing those inner objects? I want to do something like the following:

```
set c [Container new]

# (1) accessing inner1 indirectly
$c echo1 "Hallo World"

# (2) accessing inner1 dirctly
$c inner1 echo "Hallo World"
```

Is there a way to do that? Does this approache even make sense?

What I want to achieve is a nested object structure (essentially tree-like). I'd like to be able to navigate this structure by calling methods (e.g. parent, child) on the nodes. Also destroying the root should destroy all children (thats why I used `create` to create the nested objects inside the parent namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just plain use the contained object, just use its *local* name, which you should know because you `create`d it in the constructor. It doesn't need to be held in a variable; it's entirely trivial to ensure it is a unique name because it will be in a unique namespace (the instance namespace; every TclOO object has its own private namespace for this sort of thing) and you control it completely.

Exposing the inner object is most easily done using forwarding methods.
TclOO comes with two main sorts of user-configurable methods: “normal” `proc`-like methods that you declare with `method`, and forwarding methods (a bit like an `interp alias`) that you declare with `forward`. The thing that you forward to is resolved with respect to the instance namespace, which is *ultra*-useful!
In particular, you can make a `forward` method on the container class that forwards to the relevant inner object. Like this (`InsideThing` is unchanged):

```
oo::class create Container {
    constructor {} {
        puts "Created a [self] that is a Container"
        InsideThing create innerABC
        InsideThing create innerDEF
    }
    destructor {
        puts "Deleted a [self] that is a Container"
    }
    method echo1 {text} {
        # Just use the name. That's all.
        innerABC echo $text
    }
    forward inner1 innerABC
    forward inner2 innerDEF
}
```

Then you can call into the inner object like:

```
$c inner1 echo "Yo!"
```

Or you can use the intermediating normal method like this:

```
$c echo1 "Hiya!"
```

It's up to you. (The forwarded version is around 20% faster in my informal testing with a modified version of your code with trivial do-nothing `echo` method implementation. However, real code will notice the difference significantly less; microbenchmarking is rarely all that useful in reality.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I expected it to be something simple, very usefull to know that it acutally is ;)

Comment: For anyone reading along, I used `innerABC` instead of `inner1` in some places to make it clearer what name was matching up with what. That's all…